# JQuery selector builder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I was wondering if such a tool exists in a browser. You select any item on the page like a `<p>` tag nested in several div's and the tool creates a JQuery selector for it which I can copy and use in my Javascript function.

Comment: Not sure if this is enough, but Firebug displays the "path" to the current element... I don't know whether that can be copied, though (and it probably isn't in the right format for jQuery...).

Comment: you make it sound like building the selectors was rocket science.  i find it quicker to type the few characters in than to manipulate a mouse-driven selection tool.  how are you gonna build e. g. a selector that matches intermediate `a` children of every other `p` element?  when you click a particular element, say `<html><body>...<div ...><a id="a10" /><a id="a11" /><a id="a12" class="orly" /></div></body></html>` in such a tool, should the selector be `html > body > div > a:eq(2)` or `#a12' or `.orly`?  such a selection-driven selector builder would be wrong most of the time...

Comment: @just somebody, I imagine that such a tool would be as specific as possible - if the element has an ID, then use the ID...

Comment: The very same element can be selected in a thousand ways: if you have one singe `<p>` in a page, it's just `$('p')`, but this won't work if there'll be another <p>, it'll select 2 elements. Hence, need to be more exact (like `$('p:first')` or something), and the more ways the document can be shaped, the more precise and complicated the selector must be. I don't think it's possibile to state what level of complexity is enough. Finally, the ultimate solution is to use `id` or the element object itself (if the doc is changing on the fly).

There's no clear answer to your question as it is.

Comment: @culebrón: A Regular expression (regex) can be built in many ways and there are a lot of visual tools for creating the expressions. I can expect similar tools for JQuery.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should check out [SelectorGadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/). It is a JavaScript bookmarklet that allows you to interactively select items on the page and spits you out the exact targeting selector based on the DOM.

Its pretty advanced, watch the screencast!

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the element itself as a selector.  For example, using $(this) inside a click handler wraps the current element inside a jQuery object.

```
$('p').click( function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    ... more computing...
});
```

If you need a string selector for a particular element, that's going to be harder.  You'd have to recurse upward using parent() and prev() (to get offsets for similar elements at each level) unless the element itself has an id -- then you could just use it.

You may be better off creating a unique class that you can assign and referencing it that way.

```
var counter = 0;

$('p').click( function() {
   var uniq = 'paragraph-' + counter;
   ++counter;
   $(this).addClass(uniq);
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants. That would limit him to using those inside the event handlers...

Comment: Sure, but you could store the jQuery object itself in a container for use elsewhere.  I suppose if you wanted a path you could always simply recurse upward via parent() until you get to the body element.

Comment: What if the page has several p's? The tool's purpose is to create $...

Comment: Hmmm... yeah. That depends on what exactly he wants. If he's too lazy too just look the "path" up and write it down all by himself, this won't help him a lot.
Then again, the plugin would probably give him the full path, while that is not always practical etc...

Answer (score 0):

You may use also **XPather** plugin for FF as a little helper in your task.

http://xpath.alephzarro.com/

It shows XPATH of element, that may help you to understand what it is from DOM point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Chrome plugin is exactly what you are looking for: [JQuery Unique Selector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-unique-selector/cmdmlphjbobhblimniofbnlfkmpcjlgd)